# pca in matlab - 2D curve stretching

Tags: matlab, 2d, pca

I have N 3D observations taken from an optical motion capture system in XYZ form.
The motion that was captured was just a simple circle arc, derived from a rigid body with fixed axis of rotation.
I used the princomp function in matlab to get all marker points on the same plane i.e. the plane on which the motion has been done.

(See a pic representing 3D data on the plane that was found, below)

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ea9Pz20.png]

What i want to do after the previous step is to look the fitted data on the plane that was found and get the curve of the captured motion in 2D. 
In the princomp how to, it is said that

> The first two coordinates of the principal component scores give the
>   projection of each point onto the plane, in the coordinate system of
>   the plane.

(from "Fitting an Orthogonal Regression Using Principal Components Analysis" article on mathworks help site)

So i thought that if i just plot those pc scores -plot(score(:,1),score(:,2))- i'll get the motion curve. Instead what i got is this.

(See a pic representing curve data in 2D derived from pc scores, below)

[image]

The 2d curve seems stretched and nonlinear (different y values for same x values) when it shouldn't be. The curve that i am looking for, should be interpolated by just using simple polynomial (polyfit) or circle fit in matlab. 
Is this happening because the plane that was found looks like rhombus relative to the original coordinate system and the pc axes are rotated with respect to the basis of plane in such way that produce this stretch?

Then i thought that, this is happening because of the different coordinate systems of optical system and Matlab. Optical system's (ie cameras) co.sys. is XZY oriented and Matlab's default (i think) co.sys is XYZ oriented. I transformed my data to correspond to Matlab's co.sys through a rotation matrix, run again princomp but i got the same stretch in the 2D curve (the new curve just had different orientation now).

Somewhere else i read that

> Principal Components Analysis chooses the first PCA axis as that line
>   that goes through the centroid, but also minimizes the square of the
>   distance of each point to that line. Thus, in some sense, the line is
>   as close to all of the data as possible. Equivalently, the line goes
>   through the maximum variation in the data. The second PCA axis also
>   must go through the centroid, and also goes through the maximum
>   variation in the data, but with a certain constraint: It must be
>   completely uncorrelated (i.e. at right angles, or "orthogonal") to PCA
>   axis 1.

I know that i am missing something but i have a problem understanding why i get a stretched curve. What i have to do so i can get the curve right?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is a sample data file (3 columns XYZ coords for 2 markers)
w w w.sendspace.com/file/2hiezc

Comment: I don't think this will completely solve your problem, but your plot axes do not cover the same distance.  Your data spans ~55 units in the x direction, and ~250 units in the y direction.  Add the line `axis equal` after you generate your plot to fix the aspect ratio such that the unit step is the same in each direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response craigim. The "inequality" of axes isn't a real problem (at least it seems so). The curve stretch isn't just visual but a real "fixed" outcome from pca computations. If for example try to do a polyfit matlab fails to do so. In the experiment 5 LED markers where used (not shown in the pic) and all where attached across a bar with fixed axis of rotation. It seems that the two LEDS that where closer to the bar's axis of rotation caused this stretch in each of the 5 LED curves. If i exclude them and keep only the other 3 in PCA calculations, ... (continues to next comment)

Comment: ... i get more circular curves without any stretch that are suitable for a polyfit in matlab. I didn't think that in such a controllable experiment where errors are minimized, the location of markers relative close to the bar's center of rotation, would have as a consequence to "distort" PCA calculations. Looking forward for any further suggestions. Thanks again.